# how to use a rvalue reference in a switch's case

Tags: c++, switch-statement, rvalue-reference

I want to use t(rvalue reference) in a case of switch(T), but I get an error `the value of 't' is not usable in a constant expression`. How to do it the right way.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int (&&t)=5;
    int T{};
    switch(T){
        case t:   // error in this case
            cout<<t<<endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"default"<<endl;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: With all due respect, your example makes no sense at all. What again are you trying to achieve? Why are you switching on an uninitialized variable - what good do you hope that'll do? What do you expect this program to print, and why?

Comment: I'm trying to understand rvalue reference. T is unitialized (switch would use the default case for it ).

Comment: No, reading from an uninitialized variable is undefined.

Comment: my bad, I've initialized T now

Comment: Why do you expect there to be any connection between `T` and `t`? What is the nature of the connection you expect to exist between them? I still don't understand what you believe this (to me, meaningless) code is supposed to demonstrate.

Comment: I just want to know why `case t` is any different from `case 5`.

Comment: The compiler told you. `5` is a constant expression. `t` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [case labels](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) in a `switch` statement need to be constant expressions.

You can't use an rvalue reference as a case label, since it is not a constant expression. You can however use a compile time initialized variable:

```
constexpr int t = 5;
switch(...)
{
  case t : ...  // ok
}
```

Note that trying to do something like:

```
int const &&t = 5;
```

will not work either, since the initializer is not a constant expression, so there is no way that I'm aware of that lets you use an rvalue reference as a case label.

Note also, that something like:

```
int const t = ...
```

will not work unless the initializer is a constant expression (i.e. known at compile time). So:

```
int const t = 5;
```

will work, but:

```
int n = 5;
int const t = n;
```

will not.